# Batel b'shisim on a large scale

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, meat-and-milk, bitul-batel-null, size

Suppose someone is making a huge 50-gallon vat of cholent. Accidentally, an entire bag of milk breaks and spills into the cholent. There is more than 60x as much meat cholent as there is milk, so the milk should theoretically be *batel b'shisim*. But **does the fact that a non-negligible amount of milk fell into the pot** (as opposed to a couple of drops into a smaller pot) **change anything**?

Comment: If you see the milk then it's definitely not nullified

Comment: @DoubleAA, I think (an unspoken) part of the question is, does that spill _eventually_ become absorbed and nullified?

Comment: The answer is in Ran Avoda Zara. If one of the goals of the bitul is to take advantage of the added amount of food, there is non negligible amount of isur. So the question is this?

Comment: @Daniel If you still remember, can you explain what is the specific cavana of the question, there are 3 answers d/t 3 understanding of the question

Answer (score 3):

The Rambam (MT [Ma'achalot Asurot 9:10](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/968265/jewish/Maachalot-Assurot-Chapter-9.htm)) writes

> If the milk fell into the sauce or onto all the pieces and
>   it was not known on which piece [the milk] fell he should stir the
>   entire pot so that all its contents will be mixed [thoroughly]. If
>   the flavor of milk [can be detected] in the entire pot, it is
>   forbidden. If not, it is permitted. If a gentile to taste [the pot]
>   whom we can rely on cannot be found, we require a measure of sixty
>   whether for meat in milk or milk in meat. If there is one measure in
>   sixty, it is permitted. If there is less than sixty, it is
>   forbidden.

See also the [SA YD 92:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.92.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) and [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/93753/11501) for further details.

Therefore mixing the pot up to the point that the milk is dissolved into the mixture is enough to make the cholent kosher as long as there was 60 times the quantity of milk and if you cannot identify the milk anymore.

I confirmed with R Binyamin Tabady and R Yonathan Jessurun that this can be indeed relied upon in practice but of course, [consult your rabbi](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9146)
before implementing anything [you learn here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1734).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89765/discussion-between-kouty-and-mbloch).

Comment: +1 because the din is true despite I don't understand the specific link with great amount, that the question have an hava amina to be different

Answer (score -2):

I will try to redefine the question. Generally Halacha tells about a drop of milk that falls in a pot of meat.e.g. Mishna Chullin 8, 3:

> ח,ג  טיפת חלב שנפלה על חתיכה--אם יש בה בנותן טעם באותה חתיכה, נוער *(יש גורסים ניער, וזה מדגיש דווקא בדיעבד ועיין ערוך השולחן סימן מ''ב סעיף ט''ז סיכום יפה של הנושא של ביטול איסור לכתחילה במקרה זה)* את הקדירה; אם יש בה בנותן טעם באותה הקדירה, אסור.‏

In such a case we must not evaluate if the quantity added by the isur leads to a gain. So the bitul is only done to avoid a loss.

But when the quantity of isur actually present in the pot is valuable, e.g. it adds a piece to the meal, is it permitted to eat the extra piece of Tshulent.

There is halachot about this when solid pieces of Isur are mixed with Heyter, e.g. Teruma 5, 7:

> ה,ז  סאה תרומה שנפלה למאה, הגביהה ונפלה אחרת, הגביהה ונפלה אחרת--הרי זו מותרת, עד שתרבה תרומה על החולין

A din for Teruma, to extract the same quantity from the mixture.

See Chullin 100a, see SA YD 109.1.

#### But here, the milk is allowed 100% because it's not able to give a perceptible taste in the meat (to prohibit we need taste of milk in the meat and taste of meat in the milk. See Chullin 111a). So, paradoxally we have **allowed milk** in the pot and **allowed meat**, even if the quantity of milk is great, there is no hanaa from bitul Isur, because **no prohibited foods have ever been present**. (This is different conceptually from the case in which a non Casher meat was annulled. See [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/99726/9215) the explanation of the Mahari Ben Chaviv).

*See Gemara [Chulin 108a](https://he.m.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%97%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9F_%D7%A7%D7%97_%D7%90), and Rashi paragraph "Amar Leh Rava".*

Comment: I'll be happy to understand If something is wrong in my answer, there are two downvotes, but I am not able to add a correction.