# A drop of milk gets into the chicken soup, can one still eat the soup?

Tags: halacha, meat-and-milk, kashering-kosherization, bitul-batel-null

I think it has something to do with the 1/60 rule but I don't know what that is.

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya Yehuda. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. One of the things we don't do is answer specific requests for halachic decisions as they depend a lot on the context (as you can see from the comments above). As such this question might be closed but don't let this discourage yourself from browsing and learning with us. Hope to see you around!

Comment: For practical advice on halacha, please consult your local Orthodox rabbi.

Comment: How is this asking for a psak any more than any other [tag:halacha] question?

Comment: @ba Before Danny’s edit, this was written in the first person, which gave the implication that they were asking for themselves.

Comment: related: [How is batel beshishim verified practically?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/94038/11501)

Answer (score 2):

Let me offer a practical answer to what is a deceptively simple question

1. **If there is only hot soup and no meat, or if there is meat but the milk fell in the soup**: if the volume of soup (including any meat) is 60x greater than the volume of milk which fell, the dish is kosher ([SA YD 92:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.92.2?lang=bi)) and you should stir the soup ([MT Ma'achalot Asurot 9:10](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/968265/jewish/Maachalot-Assurot-Chapter-9.htm), [Kaf HaHayim 92:8](https://www.sefaria.org/Kaf_HaChayim_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.92.8.1?lang=bi)). If the soup is not 60x the volume of milk then the dish is not kosher and the pot needs to be kashered.
2. **If there is chicken in gravy and the milk fell on a piece of chicken**: if the volume of meat is 60x greater than the volume of milk which fell, the dish is kosher but one should remove a little less than an inch of meat (ca. 2cm.) around the area where the milk fell. If there is not 60x then the dish is not kosher and the pot needs to be kashered
3. **If the milk fell on a piece of chicken protruding from the soup**: this becomes really complicated: you have to ask a rav

In all cases one should **not** add more soup to make up the 1:60 ratio.

This is for *Ashkenazim* following the Rema that we don't ask a non-Jew to taste and go according to *bitul be shishim* ([SA YD 98:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.98.1?lang=bi)).

In all cases, you should [ask a *rav*](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9146) as small changes in the starting situation can have big impact on the *halacha*.

Sources: Eretz Hemda's [Living the halachic process vol. 1](http://www.eretzhemdah.org/Data/UploadedFiles/SitePages/3418-sFileRedirEn.pdf) p. 240; R Yossef Loria's fundamentals of kashrut p. 386; [Star-K](https://www.star-k.org/articles/kashrus-kurrents/611/when-its-null-and-void-understanding-batel-bshishim-one-sixtieth/) on *bitul b'shishim*

Answer (score 1):

The questioner is correct.

Shulcha aruch Yore dea 98,1

> איסור שנתערב בהיתר מין בשאינו מינו כגון חלב שנתערב בבשר יטעמנו גוי אם אומר שאין בו טעם חלב או שאומר שיש בו טעם אלא שהוא פגום מותר והוא שלא יהא סופו להשביח וצריך שלא ידע שסומכין עליו ואם אין שם גוי לטועמו משערינן בס' וכן אם הוא מין במינו כיון דליכא למיקם אטעמא משערים בס'.
>   Something forbidden to eat that got mixed into food which was permitted to eat like milk and meat (which is forbidden together) should be tasted by a gentile and if he can't taste the milk it is permitted. Alternatively if it has a rotten taste it is permitted to eat this mixture as long as it won't end up tasting good together in the future. This gentile has to be reliable and if such a person not available one measures if the milk is a ratio of 1:60 to the meat it is pemitted.

Rema Orach chaim 98,1

> (ואין נוהגים עכשיו לסמוך אגוי ומשערינן הכל בס) 
>   we don't rely o a gentile in our commuities rather we always measure a ratio of 1:60 to permit the milk/forbidden substance.

This also applies to soup with meat (when the meat is a 60th or more of the volume of the soup)even though its not pure meat because the soup becomes a neveila (forbidden like the meat "chanan") in matters of milk mixing with meat Shulchan Aruch 99,3: (note rema says Chanan with every forbidden substance that mixes with permitted substance)

> בשאר איסורים חוץ מבשר בחלב חתיכה הבלועה מאיסור מצטרפת לבטל האיסור.

And the rema Yore dea 92,4 says that liquid becomes a neveila in a case of milk and meat mix together.

**Coclusion: Ashkenazim follow the Rema who requires a ratio of 1:60 of milk against meaty soup, most Sefardim follow the Shulchan aruch and get a expert trustworthy gentile to taste the soup but if unavailable also require a ratio of 1:60 of milk against meaty soup  .**

Note: this is only whe the milk falls inadvertently into the meat soup but if one pours it in on purpose the mixture is forbidden see S.A Y.D 99,5.

Comment: What about the Shach?

Comment: are you reffering to a specific shach i'd be interested where it is @DoubleAA

Comment: The one about טעימת ישראל. If the Sefardi tastes it and doesn't taste milk, the Ashkenzi can trust him and eat it even if there isn't shishim. Point is Ashkenazim can also rely on tasting, everyone does, it's just a matter of who you trust.

Comment: does't the shach also say that relynig on people who are not expert tasters (not knowing what milk ad meat together taste like) should not be done lechatchila?

Answer (score -1):

If the amount of milk that fell in was less than 1/60 of the amount of soup than the soup may be eaten.

Comment: More precisely: if the milk didn't improve the flavor of the soup then it may be eaten. If you aren't sure or can't check, then you can generally assume that "if the amount of milk that fell in was less than 1/60 of the amount of soup than the soup may be eaten."

Comment: Source(s) please...

Comment: @DoubleAA Are you alluding to a possibility that, in order for the soup to be kosher, the milk might need to be less than one 60th of the soup, or do you mean that sometimes it may be even more than 1/60 and still be kosher?

Comment: Both. [15charac]

Comment: Batel biShishim is much more complicated than “1/60.” As DoubleAA notes, you have to account for nosein ta’am lifegam/lishevach. I recommend looking at the halachos of ta’aroves in Yoreh De’ah.